# How to get CV predictions for sklearn ElasticNetCV

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I want to take advantage of the built-in CV methods in sklearn (ElasticNetCV, LassoCV, etc.), but I can't seem to get the actual cross validation predictions. I don't mean the final predictions using the optimized model, since that is easy enough to do using ElasticNetCV.predict(X). What I want are the predictions of each fold when it was held out. Ideally I'd like to get this information for every value of alpha and L1 ratio, but even just at the optimal settings would be useful. Is this possible? Thanks.